# Concatenating strings after grouping by name and then sorting by date

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby, string-concatenation

I have this data in a data frame

```
data = [
           {'name' : 'a', 'date' : '2020-01-02', 'message' : 'there'},
           {'name' : 'b', 'date' : '2020-01-01', 'message' : 'Hello'},
           {'name' : 'a', 'date' : '2020-01-01', 'message' : 'Hi'},
           {'name' : 'b', 'date' : '2020-01-03', 'message' : 'everyone'},
           {'name' : 'c', 'date' : '2020-01-05', 'message' : 'Test'}
       ]
```

What I would like to do is group by name, then sort by date, and concatenate the message for each name so that the data looks like this

```
[
   {'name' : 'a', 'message' : 'Hi there'},
   {'name' : 'b', 'message' : 'Hello everyone'},
   {'name' : 'c', 'message' : 'Test'}
]
```

I have already been able to group by name and sort by date (after making the string into a datetime object) using this

```
df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['date'])
```

but I am not sure how you would concatenate the strings together once you have grouped and sorted the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `apply` with `join`

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('name')['message'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

  name         message
0    a        Hi there
1    b  Hello everyone
2    c            Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to avoid an `apply` invocation:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['name', 'date'], inplace=True)
>>> df

  name        date   message
2    a  2020-01-01        Hi
0    a  2020-01-02     there
1    b  2020-01-01     Hello
3    b  2020-01-03  everyone
4    c  2020-01-05      Test

>>> df['message'] = df['message'] + ' '
>>> df
 
  name        date    message
2    a  2020-01-01        Hi 
0    a  2020-01-02     there 
1    b  2020-01-01     Hello 
3    b  2020-01-03  everyone 
4    c  2020-01-05      Test 

>>> df.groupby('name')['message'].sum().str.strip()

name
a          Hi there
b    Hello everyone
c              Test
Name: message, dtype: object
```

This does a direct concatenation within groups, then strips the resulting string.